# Django ORM: AND'ing and exclude query

Tags: django-queryset, django-orm

I want to select items where more than one of the values are greater than 0.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    val1 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    val2 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    val3 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I thought these should do by eliminating items where all `val`s are 0:

```
Item.objects.exclude(val1=0, val2=0, val3=0)
Item.objects.exclude(Q(val1=0) & Q(val2=0) & Q(val3=0))
```

They both eliminate every item where a `val` is zero and return only the ones with all `val`s greater than 0. I don't want to `OR` the combinations but find a generic expression because `val`s can be more than 3.

How can the query be written? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use chained filters to do this:

```
Item.objects.filter(val1__gt=0).filter(val2__gt=0).filter(val3__gt=0)
```

Using the filter `__gt` selects only values that are greater than the value. Chaining filters acts as logical `AND` statements so this would exclude any that are 0 for all three values.

Edit:

As per your comment clarifying your actual needs, something like this may work. (It is untested)

```
Item.objects.filter((Q(val1__gt=0) & Q(val2__gt=0)) |
                    (Q(val2__gt=0) & Q(val3__gt=0)) | 
                    (Q(val1__gt=0) & Q(val3__gt=0)))
```

Binding multiple `AND` and `OR` operators in the right order should get you what you need.

Comment: but this will return only return the items which have `all` the `val`s greater than 0. I want items which has at least 2 of the `val`s greater than 0.

Comment: I didn't see that before, so I have added a different query that should handle that.

Comment: in the question i've also mentioned that i don't want to do the `OR` combinations because the values are actually more than 3 but yes this is my last resort. thanks : )

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. I am not sure how else to do that. You can maybe find a way to generate the query using a for loop and an regex to match value names.